# Error connecting to local mysql database Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table doesn't exist" using hibernate in eclipse?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have this code that I am trying to connect to mysql database in hibernate and insert an employee I have an employee table in the database user in my sql. Can anyone help me how can I solve this error?

my database in sql has the following structure
[image: database structure]
here is my configuration

```
    public class HibernateUtils {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    private static Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(List<Class> entityClasses) {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                Properties settings = new Properties();

                
                settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"); //10.10.10.15
              settings.put(Environment.USER, "root");
              settings.put(Environment.PASS, "root");
              settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");

                settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");

                settings.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");

                settings.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create-drop");

                configuration.setProperties(settings);
                
                entityClasses.forEach(entityClass -> configuration.addAnnotatedClass(entityClass));

                ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

and my pojo is

```
public class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private int id;

private String firstname;

private String lastname;
```

}

but it is giving me an error

```
    Hibernate: drop table if exists Employee
Jul 19, 2021 7:56:10 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
Hibernate: create table Employee (id integer not null auto_increment, firstname varchar(255), lastname varchar(255), primary key (id)) type=MyISAM
Jul 19, 2021 7:56:10 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
ERROR: Table 'test.employee' doesn't exist
```

Comment: can you show your db and table in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

```
settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
```

change to,

```
settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tourdb");
```

Comment: ```ERROR: Table 'tourdb.employee' doesn't exist```

Comment: after `Hibernate: drop table if exists Employee`, is db recreated successfully?

Comment: I think it is recreated successfully It is not showing me errors after ```Hibernate: drop table if exists Employee```